# What is MSVC's unordered_map::lower_bound?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl

I found out that, contrary to my expectation and the documentation, the MSVC's `std::unordered_map` and `std::unordered_multimap` (and the unordered sets, too) provide `lower_bound` and `upper_bound`.

What do these member functions do?  Is there any documentation?

I tried with MSVC 2019 and 2022 in C++20 mode; the following seems to compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
int main() {
    std::unordered_map<int, int> m;
    m.emplace(1, 1);
    std::cout << m.lower_bound(1)->first;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a non-standard extension for compatibility purposes only. It is deprecated and has the following warning:

> The hash_meow and unordered_meow containers' non-Standard lower_bound() member was provided for interface compatibility with the ordered associative containers, and doesn't match the semantics of the hash_meow or unordered_meow containers. Please use the find() member instead. You can define _SILENCE_STDEXT_HASH_LOWER_BOUND_DEPRECATION_WARNING to suppress this warning.

From yvals_core.h (`upper_bound` has a similar warning).

Your code actually doesn't compile for me, on VS 17.5 using `/std:c++20`, as I get the above "warning" (which is actually an error for me).

As to what it actually does, `lower_bound` is the same as calling `find`; `upper_bound` is a bit more complex, but still tries to find the next element after the key, using `_Find_last` (internal MS function for hash-type objects)

Comment: Adding those functions for "compatibility" was the stupidest idea ever.  If you can't uphold the contract, don't implement the function.

Comment: Thanks.  It did not produce any warning for me, with simple /std:c++20 /Ox, and I couldn't find any info in the documentation.  I discovered these functions by accident - I wanted to distinguish between ordered and unordered maps in template code using "if constexpr(requires(MapType m) { m.lower_bound(1); })" and I was surprised that unordered_map satisfied the condition.

Comment: What does `meow` (in `hash_meow` and `unordered_meow`) mean?

Comment: @Sasha, It's a short form to represent all the different forms (i.e. `set`, `map`, `multiset` and `multimap` ) https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable